# How do I remove the "\n" characters when reading my file but deleting one variable then replacing it

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to make a program that reads from a file and deletes one specific line inside of it and then puts all the data stored back to the file separated with a new line. The file uses this format:

```
Jones|20|20|00
bob|30|19|90
James|40|19|80
```

So I want to delete (backup contains this and is the line I want to delete)
`bob|30|19|90`
but the code that I am using takes away the new line and doesnt replace it but when I try to add \n to it the file doesn't want to read as it does this (adds 2 "\n"s):

```
Jones|20|20|00

James|40|19|80
```

I am using this code below:

```
def deleteccsaver(backup):
lockaccount =""
lockaccount = lockaccount.strip("\n")
with open('accounts_project.txt','r+') as f:
    newline=[]
    for line in f.readlines():
        newline.append(line.replace(backup, lockaccount).strip("\n"))
with open('accounts_project.txt','w+') as f:
    for line in newline:
            f.writelines(line +"\n")
    f.close()
    resetlogin()
```

Please help as I dont know how to add the \n back without it appearing as "\n\n"
Without the "\n "it appears as:

```
Jones|20|20|00James|40|19|80
```

Any suggestions:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I am doing here is reading the entire file at once, please don't do this if you have a very very big file. After reading all file contents at once, I am making a list out of it using "\n" as a delimiter. Read about split function in python to know more about it. Then from the list I am replacing the backup with lockaccount, as you have been doing the same, these are the names of variables that you are using, hope I did not confuse between them in this case. Then it will be saved to a new file after adding new line after each element of list, i.e. each line of the previous file. This will cause the result file to have all the contents as previous file, but removing what you wanted to remove. I see that lockaccount is itself an empty string, so adding it might create a newline in your file. In case you dont want lockaccount to replace the backup variable in the file, just remove the backup from the list using `contents.remove(backup)` instead of `contents[contents.index(backup)] == lockaccount` keeping the rest of the code same. Hope this explains better.

```
def deleteccsaver(backup):
    lockaccount =""
    lockaccount = lockaccount.strip("\n")
    with open('accounts_project.txt','r+') as f:
        contents = f.read().split("\n")
        if backup in contents:
            contents[contents.index(backup)] = lockaccount
        new_contents = "\n".join(contents)
    with open('accounts_project.txt','w+') as f:
        f.write(new_contents)
    resetlogin()
```

Comment: Your answer will be much better if you explain the problem, how to resolve it and what you did to solve it. Also, the above coment must be deleted as it's worthless. Please, have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Now I get this (TypeError: index() takes at least 1 argument (0 given))

Comment: @AlexandreB. Thanks buddy. I will take care of it now.

Comment: @Bond007 Really sorry I did not tested this code before submitting, Can you check it again?

Comment: @Bond007 Sorry I wrote = as == in `contents[contents.index(backup)] = lockaccount`. Please check. Sorry this is too many mistakes in one code from my side. :D:D

Comment: @Bond007 Also I think that a newline might be appearing because you are replacing backup with an empty newline. That might be making it appear as if there is still an empty line. In answer I have mentioned exactly what to do in that scenario.

Comment: Now I know what was generating the \n. lockaccount did so I did what you mentioned: contents.remove(backup) and it works but my last question is will it work on a massive file as it is likely to get massive.

Comment: @Bond007 It should work for fairly large file, should not work for massively big files, readlines() might not work too, in that case one must read and do things in buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You are priting a newline character after each element in the list. So, if you replace a line with the empty string, well, you will get an empty line.

Try to simply skip over the line you want to delete:

```
if line == backup:
    contiune
else:
    lines.append(...)
```

PS. There is room for improvment in the code above, but I'm on the phone, I will get back with an edit later if nobody gets ahead of me

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `newline = '\n'.join(newline)` after your first for loop and then just write it into the `accounts_project.txt` file without a loop.
The code should then look like:

```py
def deleteccsaver(backup):
lockaccount =""
lockaccount = lockaccount.strip("\n")
with open('accounts_project.txt','r+') as f:
    newline=[]
    for line in f.readlines():
        newline.append(line.replace(backup, lockaccount).strip("\n"))
    newline = '\n'.join(newline)
with open('accounts_project.txt','w+') as f:
    f.write(newline)
    f.close() # you don't necessarily need it inside a with statement
    resetlogin()
```

**Edit:**

Above code still results in

```py
Jones|20|20|00

James|40|19|80
```

as output.

That's because during the replacement loop an empty string will be appended to `newline` (like `newline: ['Jones|20|20|00','','James|40|19|80']`) and `newline = '\n'.join(newline)` will then result in `'Jones|20|20|00\n\nJames|40|19|80'`.

A possible fix can be to replace:

```py
for line in f.readlines():
    newline.append(line.replace(backup, lockaccount).strip("\n"))
```

with

```py
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if line != backup:
        newline.append(line)
```

Comment: Ok, I tested it with your provided data and it will result in the desired output.What type of error you get?

Comment: Sorry again. It results in Jones|20|20|00, "new line", James|40|19|80

Comment: Did you notice the change in the second `with` block, that it is no longer `f.writelines(line +"\n")`, but `f.write(newline)`?

Comment: I have tried the same thing what you showed now but it is quite the same as what I did: f.writelines(line +"\n") and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleteccsaver(backup):
lockaccount =""
lockaccount = lockaccount.strip("\n")
with open('accounts_project.txt','r+') as f:
    contents = f.read().split("\n")
    if backup in contents:
        contents.remove(backup)
    new_contents = "\n".join(contents)
with open('accounts_project.txt','w+') as f:
    f.write(new_contents)
resetlogin()
```

Comment: will this approach work for a massive file as well?